# LINQ Many to Many With In or Contains Clause (and a twist)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a many to many table structure called PropertyPets.  It contains a dual primary key consisting of a PropertyID (from a Property table) and one or more PetIDs (from a Pet table).

Next I have a search screen where people can multiple select pets from a jquery multiple select dropdown.  Let's say somebody selects Dogs and Cats.

Now, I want to be able to return all properties that contain BOTH dogs and cats in the many to many table, PropertyPets.  I'm trying to do this with Linq to Sql.

I've looked at the Contains clause, but it doesn't seem to work for my requirement:

```
var result = properties.Where(p => search.PetType.Contains(p.PropertyPets));
```

Here, search.PetType is an int[] array of the Id's for Dog and Cat (which were selected in the multiple select drop down).  The problem is first, Contains requires a string not an IEnumerable of type PropertyPet. And second, I need to find the properties that have BOTH dogs and cats and not just simply containing one or the other.

Thank you for any pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using a nested where clause.

You need to filter `p.PropertyPets` using `contains` - return all rows where `PetID` is in `search.PetType`.

Then only return rows from `properties` where all search id's have been found - eg `number of rows >= number of serach id's`

All together:

```
var result = from p in properties
             where p.PropertyPets.Where(c => search.PetType.Contains(c.PetID)).Count() >= search.PetType.Count()
             select p;
```

Comment: Geoff - It works!!  Thank you.  Very concise and looking pretty creative to boot.

Answer (score 0):

For the part where `Contains` requires a `string` would not be true, `Contains` should require an int if your `search.PetType` is `int[]`. That means that you need to "convert" `p.PropertyPets` into an `int`. To convert `p.PropertyPets` to `IEnumerable<int>` you need to select the `PropertyID` field: `p.PropertyPets.Select(propertyPet => propertyPet.PropertyID)`, but that won't get you a single int as required but a whole bunch. (`.First()` would give you one int but not solve your problem.

What you really want to do is

```
var result = properties.Where(p =>
    search.PetType.Except(p.PropertyPets.Select(propertyPet => 
                            propertyPet.PropertyID)).Count() == 0);
```

But `Except` is not available in LINQ2SQL.

The best option I can find is to apply `Contains` for each item in `search.PetType`.

Something like this:

```
var result = properties;
foreach(var petType in search.PetType)
{
    result = from p in result
             where p.PropertyPets.Select(propertyPet =>
                   propertyPet.PropertyID).Contains(petType)
             select p;
}
```

Comment: Albin- This didn't work for me. Conceptually, it seems like it ought to. I added a 'Select p' at the end as the compiler was complaining, but still no go.  Result ends up with no properties even if I select a pet that the property does have.